# how to mention a json file for elasticsearch which can be used by kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have to show my log file(a json file) to a dashboard of kibana. I configured elasticsearch and kibana.

I tried giving elasticsearch.yml   path.data: C:\Users\Rajesh\Desktop\temp (where my logs are),but while using dashboard if i am searching for any string it gives 0 Results.

Could anyone please guide me? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Logstash](http://logstash.net/docs/1.3.3/tutorials/getting-started-centralized) to read your logfile and then output to elasticsearch. Then use kibana to view it.

Logstash has a lot of plugin help you to do this.

Here is an example for your reference. This is the Logstash  [configuration](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/configuration). We read all the json data from a file and then output to elasticsearch.

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/path/to/your/json/file"
        codec => json_lines {
        }
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
         cluster => "abc"
    }
}
```

Comment: I went through the docummentation of logstach, but not able to integate it to KIBANA. Which file i need to edit for this input and how do we run LOGSTACH?

Comment: http://logstash.net/docs/1.3.3/tutorials/getting-started-simple. You need to know how to run logstash first. Then, write your own configuration file to read the logs and send to elasticsearch. Elasticsearch will index your logs and then you can use KIBANA connect to elaticsearch and get your result.